# react-router-dom params doesn't include question marks which are present in URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

**react-router-dom params doesn't include question marks which are present in URL.**

Suppose the URL param is this: **'/I-am-John-Doe-Who-Are-You?'**
But when I console.log 'react-router-dom' params , it log's just **'I-am-John-Doe-Who-Are-You'**, not the **? question mark** which is at the end of URL.

And **when URL param contains two question mark's** in it like **'/I-am-John-Doe?-Who-Are-You?'**
then it will just extract params till the first question mark(question mark still isn't inluded) like **'I-am-John-Doe'**

I want to send these params to the my server's Rest API but this is giving me problem now.

Comment: The problem is that question mark in the url is used to mark the start of a [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?` in url represents optional parameters,
so when you see a url like
`URL?something=ppp`

that means parameter `something` = `ppp`

so you can not include `?`

Comment: You do a work around, replace question mark with some unique string in front end, and then replace that unique string back to question mark